# Чем отличается api от sdk?

Tags: api, терминология, sdk

вроде и то и то предоставляет доступ к какому-либо функционалу

Answer (score 9):

**SDK** - это набор функционала(библиотек) и утилит для разработки.
Собственно **SDK** и предоставляет реализацию некоторого **API**, это оболочка **API's**, которая упрощает работу для разработчиков.

**API:**

- набор готовых классов, процедур, функций, структур и констант,
  предоставляемых приложением для использования во внешних программных
  продуктах
- это **интерфейс**, похоже на спецификацию телефонной системы или
  электропроводки в вашем доме.
- это список того, что можно вызывать и какого ждать результата.

**SDK**:

- пакет реальных инструментов внедрения. Это, как комплект, который позволяет вам подключиться к телефонной системе или электрической проводке.
- это библиотеки, в которых реализованы вызываемые функции + файлы
  необходимые для подключения этих библиотек

Answer (score 5):

API (Application programming interface) - это описание интерфейса чего-либо. Набор правил по которым что-то должно работать.

SDK (Software development kit) - это набор инструментов для работы с чем-то.

Вы можете рассматривать свой любимый язык программирования как API (набор правил синтаксиса и поведения), а свою любимую среду - как SDK (набор инструментов для написания, проверки и отладки кода).

Answer (score 4):

**API** штука очень абстрактная. Это лишь словарь для перевода обращений к сервису в действия. Указывает "куда обращаться, чтобы попросить сервис сделать <...>".

"Куда обращаться" может описываться разными способами в зависимости от того, как к сервису осуществляется доступ:

- Для сетевых API это адреса узлов, пути в пределах узлов, спецификации для запроса, ответа, сообщений/датаграмм или всего протокола связи.
- Для библиотек под языки программирования или написания плагинов это доступные потребителям функции/классы/интерфейсы/и т. п.

В какой-то мере можно считать, что API это спецификация/документация. Ничего более вещественного он из себя не представляет. Один API может быть описан различными способами, но при этом быть одним и тем же API.

**SDK** же вещь гораздо более осязаемая: это комплект программного обеспечения для разработки под некий API. Посему он неминуемо *содержит описание API*, но во вполне конкретной форме, связанной с тем, из какой среды к API осуществляется доступ.

---

К примеру, для HTTP-сервиса API это спецификация того, какие HTTP-запросы способен принимать сервис: какими могут быть методы + пути + заголовки + тела запросов, какие у каждого запроса будут последствия и какие на них придут ответы.

А SDK для такого сервиса для некоего языка программирования может представлять собой заранее заголовленный набор классов, в котором спрятана HTTP-шная природа интерфейса, и обращение к сервису выглядит просто как вызов функции. Такой SDK практически преобразует один API в другой, более удобный для разработки с конкретными технологиями.

Answer (score 2):

Если совсем кратко - SDK (software development KIT) и API (application programming INTERFACE) - применительно к реальности андроид, характеризуют одно и то же с разных сторон.

Т.е. библиотека с набором описанных в ней функциональностей - с т.з. **SDK** - *пакет данных*, *инструментов*, с помощью которых реализуется функциональность, а для **API** это - набор *возможностей интерфейса* в разрабатываемом приложении, иначе - *программируемый интерфейс*.